# Measure an area in Google Maps using Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-maps, computational-geometry, area, polygons

I picked many points on the edge of a lake in Google Maps and I already have xdata, ydata of the points. some people tell me that I should use the method of fitting a Gaussian function for these points and then measure the area of the lake. but I can't understand how I can measure the area of the lake after I fit all of points with Gaussian process. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Lake Superior is 563 km in length, which covers an angle of 0.014 radians. The relative difference between the arc and the chord is about 2.5 x 10^-5, and the error on the area will be less than twice that. Is it worth doing the correction ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Not anymore!

Comment: @YvesDaoust 563km is 0.014 part of Earth circumference. It is 0.014*2pi=0.088 radians.

Comment: @Ante: that's right, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean to use the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula), also known as Gauss' area formula. There is no Gaussian fitting here.